# XAMPP creating directories and files are read only

Tags: php, xampp, mamp

I just recently switched from MAMP to XAMPP and I am now having issues creating folders and files on my system. When using this exact code on MAMP I could create directories and files with Read & Write permission, now on XAMPP this same code is only creating directories and files with Read only permission. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
if(!is_dir($storeDirectory)){
        try{
            @mkdir($storeDirectory, 0777, true);
            chown($storeDirectory, 0755);
            chmod($storeDirectory, 0777);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
        }
    }
```

Here's a screen shot of what my directories and files look like.

[image]

Comment: Is `0755` an user? If not, you're using `chown` wrong. https://secure.php.net/chown

Comment: Looks like this fixed it: http://constant.co.za/fix-permissions-on-xampp-osx/